# structuring a utility class in typescript with function currying

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, currying

Updated

So i am creating a function in preCheckService called getData, which i want to call from other components. But for some reason, i am not able to call that function, how can i make getData public function so it can be called from components

### pre-check.service.ts

```
import {Component,Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {HttpModule, Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import Util from './Util';


@Injectable()
export class preCheckService{

    u:Util;
     mode:string="local";

    constructor(private http: Http ){
        this.u = new Util();
    }
    getData(){
        var u =this.u.getPreCheckDefinitions(this.mode);
        return u();

    }

}
```

### Util.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {HttpModule, Http} from "@angular/http";
import {subscribeOn} from "rxjs/operator/subscribeOn";

export default class Util{
    constructor(private http: Http){
    }

    getPreCheckDefinitions = type =>{
        switch (type){
            case 'server':
                return  function getData(){
                    return this.http.post("server/PreCheck/preCheckDefs.do", {radBusLine : 1}).map(
                        (res) => res.json()
                    )
                };
            case 'local':
                return  function getData(){
                    return this.http.get("app/data/preCheckData.json").map(
                        (res) => res.json()
                    )
                };
        }
    };
}
```

and i am getting below error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
```

Comment: Ok, you've got mode set to 'dev' by default. And what's then? There's no function? This makes perfect sense, because there's no case for 'dev'! Please, always state how you use the code and what is error message, if any. 'i am not able to call that function' can mean anything. Literally.

Comment: that was typo but i was running with correct mode set to 'local' but same error

Comment: **What** error? **How** was it set?

Comment: ok i have updated the code based on Luci's advise. but error i am now getting is different, 'this' is undefined

Comment: `Util` doesn't have `@Injectable()`. Returned function is not an arrow and won't have proper `this`.

Comment: Having Util class and returning a function from its method looks like bad class design. There's nothing 'utilitarian' in what getPreCheckDefinitions does, it should be a part of preCheckService. I would suggest to look at existing answers.

Comment: its not part of design, but i need to be able to switch from local data source to server pretty frequently, now i would do this without util class, but in my case, i need http.get method for local url and http.post for server url, btw i changed to arrow function and 'this' is still not resolving

Comment: Your util.ts is certainly logic that should be in a service.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make getData a method of your service.?

```
@Injectable()
export class preCheckService{

    u:Util;
     mode:string="dev";

    constructor(private http: Http ){
        this.u = new Util();
        this.initialize();
    }
    getData(){
        return this.u.getPreCheckDefinitions(this.mode);

    }

}
```

or maybe your getPreCheckDefinition to be changed like below. Otherwise 'this' will not be known at the time of call

```
getPreCheckDefinitions(type){
        switch (type){
            case 'server':
                return this.http.post("server/PreCheck/preCheckDefs.do", {radBusLine : 1}).map(
                        (res) => res.json()
                    );
            case 'local':
               return this.http.get("app/data/preCheckData.json").map(
                        (res) => res.json()
                    );

        }    
    }
```

This way the getPreCheckDefinitions will return an observable.

Comment: i tried this method, but for some reason i am getting this error EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.precheckservice.getData(...).subscribe is not a function

Comment: You might be right. The http service returns an observable. You should subscribe to that observable in order to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes,

1. Services that are injectable can be reused across components just by injecting it into the contructor.
2. You are returning an nothing in your below method which should be

   ```
   getPreCheckDefinitions(type):Observable<any>{
     ....
   }
   ```
3. Why are you using two separate classes to achieve this.

Possible Solution might suggest with my **[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/XFzr6c7fRqsbSJbtThe1?p=info)**

Comment: i need two different types of method in two different scenarios, http.get for local and http.post for server, however now 'this' context is undefined